# Best way to link to pages, in order to let URL appear without the .html extension?

Tags: html

What do you guys think is the best way to link to other website pages of a website, in order to remove the .html extension visible in website URL?

Assume I have the following pages:

- index.html
- page1.html
- page2.html
- pagex.html

What is the best way to link to these pages?

- `<a href="page1.html">page1</a>`
- creating subfolders named "page1", "page2", and so on, with individual "index.html" files, and referral in the form of:

  ```
  <a href="/page1">page1</a>
  ```
- Use `<a href="page1">page1</a>` and set .htaccess to `MultiViews`

Comment: "What do you guys think" sounds a lot like an opinion-based question rather than one with a definitive answer.

Comment: What's wrong with a dead simple `src="page1.html"`?! It works, it doesn't need anything extra, it's standard compliant, it's fine. Unless you can tell us why you possibly *wouldn't* want this and what else you'd want, go with it.

Comment: I agree with you that there is no definitive answer to tis question, as it might be a preference based one. With regard to your suggestion, @deceze, how does       'src="page1.html"'     refer to linking to other webpages? I am asking this question because I do not think 'websitename/page1.html' looks really need. 'websitename/page1' looks better.

Comment: I meant `href="page1.html"`, sorry.

Comment: So your actual question is *how to best have the URL appear without the .html extension?*

Comment: You are right, @deceze. Reframed question to: Best way to link to pages, in order to let URL appear without the .html extension? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to divide your page up in sections you have an admin section? make a folder nameed admin and make your path as so admin/index.html so just every section on your page should have a folder and files inside that folder but i do not believe there is any guidelines to this so it is just my opionion

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file, use a rewrite directive:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.html
```

This rule says: *if the requested file does not exist, (internally) append an .html to it.* That means the URL will show `/page1`, which will fit the `RewriteCond`, and internally the request will be treated as if `/page1.html` had been requested. That's the most straight forward way to map arbitrary URLs of your choice to arbitrary files on disk. Your links would then use *the URL* `href="page1"`.

Also see [Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772/476)

Comment: It sounds good. Are there any reasons to assume Googlebot will have any  trouble in indexing the website? I mean, `href="page1` will be appended by `.html`  by the server. Will the indexing by Google do the same? Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the server does or doesn't do. When you visit ***the URL*** `/page1`, you see your site. Done. It looks exactly the same to your browser as it does to Google.